# How can I make my friends understand islam is the truth?

Tags: quran, history, non-muslim, miracles

Please provide me some good points to present to my nonbeliever friends about islam.
They are always telling me its old barbarian and non scientific like this.
what should i say to them in response?

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.speed-light.info/miracles_of_quran/) could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so start to telling them some events of life of PBUH like how he did justice b/w people, how he spread words of islam, why islam is better than others, try to teach them the basics like how we can say that there is one God who created us etc etc, you can take examples from surah e rahman etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the harsh response. But you are the best reflection of Islam to them.
Only Allah can give hidayah and haters will always hate. All you have to do is keep believing and show conviction and learn some about the faith your friends follow. Make your friends introspect about their religion. I'm sure they had a troubled past as well. Ups and downs are with every tribe, race, sex and even religion. If everyone says 2+2 is 5 it won't change the fact that its 4. Truth is truth no matter how many people deny it. As long as you're willing to weather that wind. Hope it helps.
And Allah knows best

Answer (score 0):

Send them the Quraan , the Message of God, to read. Nothing is better than this.

Comment: Hello sara, thank you for your answer. We know the Qur'an is the truth and if they read it they will also understand that. But what I need is some good points to make them read it or atleat consider reading about islam.

Comment: Well, your question then should have said (how to generate interest in them to read the Quraan or know about Islam,you asked about how to make them understand the truth, and studying the Quraan is the ultimate way to know the truth, that's why Allah sent it down. So to let them start reading the Quraan, they should be sincere in looking for the truth, and they should reflect on their life, Why are they here, where are they going, and the purpose of this world,, when they start sincerely looking for answers, they are ready to read the Quraan.